# How do I (re)broadcast a mjpegstream using html5 and C#?

Tags: c#, html, html5-canvas

So far I have a C# project that has an event trigerred by new frames from an IPcam (stream in mjpeg). Those frames (as a video) I want to display to a webpage, so they are vieweble by all sorts of devices like iphones, android devices and other PC's. I think a HTML5 canvas is the way to go, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, altough the performance could be better:

I use VLC to rebroadcast the MJPEGstream as an mp4 one (h264/mp3) via HTTP protocol. Next I create a webpage that displays this stream using video-tags.